# Получить значение по клику JQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть такой код:

```
<div class="item">
  <div class="name">Ivan</div>
  <div class="last_name">Ivanov</div>
  <div class="age">25</div>

  <button class="get">Get info</button>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <div class="name">Vladimir</div>
  <div class="last_name">Sidorov</div>
  <div class="age">36</div>

  <button class="get">Get info</button>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <div class="name">Maria</div>
  <div class="last_name">
    Sidorova
    <div class="maiden_name">Ivanova</div>
  </div>
  <div class="age">35</div>

  <button class="get">Get info</button>
</div>
...
```

Необходимо при клике на кнопку "Get info", получить имя, фамилию, девичью фамилию (maiden_name), возраст в текущем div'е (item). Как это сделать при помощь JQuery?

Comment: сами пробовали что-нибудь?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

обходим циклом все блоки, находим в них кнопки и присваиваем клик, в котором получаем информацию из этого блока, для last_name получаем текст из первой текстовой ноды, для остальных напрямую через text()

```js
   $(function() {
     $(".item").each(function(indx, el) {
       $(".get", el).click(function() {
         var name = $(".name", el).text(),
           last_name = $.trim($(".last_name", el).contents().eq(0).text()),
           age = $(".age", el).text(),
           maiden_name = $(".maiden_name", el).text(),
           res = [name, last_name, age];
         maiden_name && res.push(maiden_name)
         alert(res)

       })

     });
   })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
  <div class="name">Ivan</div>
  <div class="last_name">Ivanov</div>
  <div class="age">25</div>

  <button class="get">Get info</button>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <div class="name">Vladimir</div>
  <div class="last_name">Sidorov</div>
  <div class="age">36</div>

  <button class="get">Get info</button>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <div class="name">Maria</div>
  <div class="last_name">
    Sidorova
    <div class="maiden_name">Ivanova</div>
  </div>
  <div class="age">35</div>

  <button class="get">Get info</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Приводить код решения, это конечно хорошо, но стоит пояснять что именно происходит в коде

Comment: @Grundy добавил описание, так понятнее стало?

Comment: Определенно лучше чем было :)

Answer (score 1):

Событие клика на кнопку, думаю знаете как вешать?

теперь в событии получаем родительский элемент кнопки

```
var parent = $( "button.get" ).parent()
```

Ну а после не составит особого труда в родительском элементе найти дочерние элементы с фамилией и именем

```
$( parent ).find( "div.name" )
$( parent ).find( "div.last_name" )
```

Значение из DIV вытягиваются командой html()

```
$(last_name).html()
```

Comment: сделал вот так: https://jsfiddle.net/zb4dL4fe . Почему не работает?

Comment: @XenK, потому что всех сразу выбираете

Comment: `var parent = $( "button.get" ).parent()` получает родителей **всех** кнопок а не конкретно той которую нажали